# Finding the biggest number divisible by other

Tags: algorithm

I need to prepare an algorithm, which will display `n-th` digit (counting from right) of the biggest number divisible by `B-1` where `B` is the base of specified number system. The number can only consist of digits provided in the input.

So for example: The base of number system is `3`, the provided digits are `[0, 1, 2]` and I'm looking for `2nd` digit. So that I need to find `2nd` digit of the biggest number consisted of `0, 1, 2` divisible by `2`. In this case the result will be `2`, because the biggest number was 20<sub>3</sub>.

I've tried to find this algorithm in many ways, but I cannot find any connection between input and output values.

Comment: Could you please provide some more examples?

Comment: @Abrixas2 When the base is `10` and digits are `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, the `8th` number is `7` because `9876543210`. And when the base is `4` and the digits are `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, the `1st` number is `0` because `11100`

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about algorithm so basically I 'd do:

1. Generate biggest number from digits (it means sort them in desc order)
2. check if it is divisible by B-1
3. If yes sucess just return n-th digit if no go to step 1. but generate next number (by swaping different digits)

Second approach. Not efficient in most cases.

1. Generate all possible numbers
2. Sort in desc order
3. Get first divisible by B - 1 and return n-th digit

Comment: I was thinking about that, but there is time limit. I cannot generate whole number, but only calculate the exact n-th digit (somehow).

Comment: @Hadenir How can you know n-th number if you haven't generated whole number?
Is there any limit for B? If B is small it is possible you have good formulas for checking if number is divisible by 2,3,4,5,8,9,10,11,25 but if B can be any number I don't think it is possible without generating number by number and checking.